# Global data about compulsory swimming lessons in schools or rates of population that can swim

Tags: data-request, sports, education, global

I saw [this post on Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=22482731) and was curious about a dataset that has information about countries and their approach to compulsory teaching of swimming.

There are many datasets about drowning rates ([see my comment for links](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=22483373)), but I'd like to correlate those to the prevalence of swimming lessons for children, either in schools or otherwise a government initiative. Or, percentages of population that can swim, by age groups if possible.

Any machine readable format (even PDF tables) and any license is fine to get me started.